# why does not-query is invalid ？

Tags: marklogic

As my title says, I met some problem when I change the position for not-query, then I found that not-query does not work. It looks like it disappeared. I give an example as below.

```
cts:element-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","doc"), 
    cts:and-query(
    (cts:or-query((cts:and-query(
        (cts:collection-query("xxxx"), 
            cts:or-query((
                cts:directory-query("/xxx/", "1"),
                cts:directory-query("/xxxx/", "1"), 
                cts:directory-query("/xxxxxx/", "1"), 
                cts:directory-query("/xx/x/", "1"),
                cts:directory-query("/xxxxx/", "1")), ()),
            cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","apple"), "=", "xxxxxxx",("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"), 1), 
            cts:or-query(cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","banana"), "SHANGHAI", ("lang=en"), 0), ())), ()),
            cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","orange"), "123456", ("lang=en"), 0), 0)), ()), 
    cts:not-query(cts:element-attribute-range-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","groupid"), fn:QName("","isGood"), "=", "false", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"), 1), 0)
    ), 
    ()), 
())
```

Is there any god would help me with this. I am a new guy for marklogic, so I really need your help.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that is wrong with your `cts:not-query()` is that you have two parameters being sent to that function. It accepts one.

For instance, this:

```
cts:not-query(
  cts:element-attribute-range-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","groupid"), fn:QName("","isGood"), "=", "false", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"), 1),
  0
)
```

Should just be:

```
cts:not-query(
  cts:element-attribute-range-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","groupid"), fn:QName("","isGood"), "=", "false", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"), 1)
)
```

In the `cts:element-attribute-range-query` you are sending `1` as the 6th parameter to indicate a weight.

It seems that maybe you were trying to set `0` on your `cts:not-query` either as a weight, or was just a mistake. Sometimes it is difficult to keep track of all the nested parenthesis, so formatting and/or `let` variables and combining can help make it easier to read.

If you had multiple queries that you wanted to negate, you would send in a sequence of queries to the `cts:not-query()`, and in order for it to be one parameter would need to wrap in parenthesis. For example:

```
cts:not-query( (cts:word-query("foo"), cts:word-query("bar")) )
```

Comment: well, you are right, I should publish a question with a correct format

Answer (score 0):

The not-query is invalid because it is not followed by a valid query. The not-query needs to be followed by a valid query in order for it to be valid.

```
cts:element-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","doc"), 
cts:and-query(
    cts:collection-query("xxxx"), 
    cts:or-query(
        cts:directory-query("/xxx/", "1"),
        cts:directory-query("/xxxx/", "1"), 
        cts:directory-query("/xxxxxx/", "1"), 
        cts:directory-query("/xx/x/", "1"),
        cts:directory-query("/xxxxx/", "1")
    ),
    cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","apple"), "=", "xxxxxxx",("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"), 1), 
    cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","banana"), "SHANGHAI", ("lang=en"), 0),
    cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","orange"), "123456", ("lang=en"), 0), 0),
    cts:not-query(cts:element-attribute-range-query(fn:QName("http://www.test/jeremy","groupid"), fn:QName("","isGood"), "=", "false", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"), 1), 0)
), 
()
```

)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give me some document about your answer, because I wanna learn more about it.  I would appreciate it if you do so :)

Comment: Sure, this:
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-query
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:and-query
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:collection-query
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:directory-query
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-range-query
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:not-query
https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-attribute-range-query

Comment: So , you mean that if I exchanged the position of `cts:not-query(cts:element-value-query(fn:QN ......`  and `    cts:element-value-query(fn:QName.....` , it would work right?

Comment: this smells like a ChatGPT answer